# A compact set $X$ is only locally conneted in on point but not locally connected in other points in $X$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, locally-connected

When study the theorem of boundary correspondence in complex analysis, I come into connact with the concept of Locally Connectedness and several examples.

**Definition:** A compact set $X\subset\mathbb{C}$  is said to be locally connected at $x$ if for every $\epsilon>0$ , there is a connected open neighbourhood $E$ of $x$ such that $\mathrm{diam}(E)<\epsilon$(diameter). The topology of $X$ is induced by the usual topology of $\mathbb{C}$.

Then I have two questions as follows:

> Is there a connceted compact set $X\subset\mathbb{C}$ which contains more than one point satiesfying
>
> 1. $X$ is only locally conneted in on point but not locally connected in other points in $X$;
> 2. $X$ is only not locally conneted in on point butlocally connected in other points in $X$.

Appreciate any help! And if you shall use some theorems, please quote them clearly.

Answer (score 1):

The cone over the Cantor set is locally connected at its vertex only, see Example 129 in *Counterexamples in Topology* by Steen and Seebach.
Exercise 5.22 in Nadler's *Continuum Theory* asks you to show that the set of points at which a continuum is not locally connected is dense in itself, so your second example does not exist.